# Would FileChannel.read read less bytes than specified if there's enough data?

Tags: java, nio

For example I have a file whose content is：

```
abcdefg
```

then i use the following code to read 'defg'.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
int read = channel.read(bb, 3);
assert(read == 4);
```

Because there's adequate data in the file so can I suppose so? Can I assume that the method returns a number less than limit of the given buffer only when there aren't enough bytes in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I assume that the method returns a number less than limit of the given buffer only when there aren't enough bytes in the file?

The Javadoc says:

> a read might not fill the buffer

and gives some examples, and

> returns the number of bytes read, possibly zero, or -1 if the channel has reached end-of-stream.

This is NOT sufficient to allow you to make that assumption.

In practice, you are likely to always get a full buffer when reading from a file, modulo the end of file scenario.  And that makes sense from an OS implementation perspective, given the overheads of making a system call.

But, I can also imagine situations where returning a half empty buffer might make sense.  For example, when reading from a locally-mounted remote file system over a slow network link, there is some advantage in returning a partially filled buffer so that the application can start processing the data.  Some future OS may implement the `read` system call to do that in this scenario.  If assume that you will always get a full buffer, you may get a surprise when your application is run on the (hypothetical) new platform.

Another issue is that there *are* some kinds of stream where you will *definitely* get partially filled buffers.  Socket streams, pipes and console streams are obvious examples.  If you code your application assuming file stream behavior, you could get a nasty surprise when someone runs it against another kind of stream ... and fails.

Comment: The Javadocs **do** specify that there is no guarantee that the number of bytes requested will be read.

Comment: @Grodriguez ... that's what I said.

Comment: You said "The javadoc does not specify what will happen, apart from saying that you will only get zero characters if you are at the end of file (or the equivalent)." But the Javadoc does specify much more than that. It explicitly states that you cannot assume that the requested number of bytes will be read, and that the only guarantee is that in blocking mode, at least one byte will be read.

Comment: @Grodriguez - *"you cannot assume that the requested number of bytes will be read"* is **NOT** a specification of what will happen.  Rather, it is a statement that something is **unspecified**.  When I said *"does not specify what will happen"*, I chose my words very carefully.

Comment: @Stephen: You are of course right. I guess I've seen so many people making wrong assumptions on this topic that I have become kind of trigger happy. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I do find sometimes on some Linux OS the method doesn't read bytes less than both specified and available. But when I wrote some code to test it, it never happen. Anyway i'll change my code to: while(bb.hasRemaining()) fc.read(bb)...

Comment: 0 at end of file? My copy of the Javadoc says "The number of bytes read, possibly zero, or -1 if the channel has reached end-of-stream", i.e. -1 at end of stream and 0 just means "no data right now."

Comment: @Trejkaz - You misread / misunderstood what I said.  I said that it does not specify how many characters you will get when you call `read`; i.e. what the Question is asking about.  Obviously, for a given number of characters read, the javadoc *does* specify what the return value will be, and lots of other things.  And I did not say that `read(..)` returns zero at EOF.  I said that it reads zero characters at EOF.

Comment: @StephenC what I read (and what I still read) is: "you will only get zero characters if you are at the end of file". I interpreted "get" to mean the result from the call, but I guess you interpret it as the values being put into the buffer. In either case, the Javadoc doesn't actually say that at all and it seems perfectly valid to get a 0 return.

Comment: @Trejkaz - as I said, you are misinterpreting what I said.  By the way ... I am not "interpreting" what I wrote.  I'm telling you what I meant, and what I say on that topic is ... definitive.  For the record, viewing the `read()` method as (primarily) a getter for the number of characters read is (IMO) a weird way of looking at it.

Comment: @StephenC I'm sure it would be, but that's OK, that isn't how I view the method. It's just how "get" sounds when you say it in the context of talking about the behaviour of any method.

Comment: @StephenC also it is still the case that 0 can be returned at a location other than the end of the file...

Comment: @StephenC I found your wording confusing too, although I can see what was meant. I replaced it with *verbatim* quotes from the Javadoc, which nobody can argue with.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general **you cannot assume that the number of bytes read will be equal to the number of bytes requested**, even if there are bytes left to be read in the file.

If you are reading from a local file, chances are that the number of bytes requested will actually be read, but this is by no means guaranteed (and won't likely be the case if you're reading a file over the network).

See the documentation for the [`ReadableByteChannel.read(ByteBuffer)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html) method (which applies for `FileChannel.read(ByteBuffer)` as well). Assuming that the channel is in blocking mode, the only guarantee is that at least one byte will be read.